# The Weingarten map in three dimensions

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

The differential of the Gaussian map AKA the Weingarten map (with a minus sign) in three dimensions is defined as :

\begin{align}
W: T_{p} M \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow T_{p} M \subset \mathbb{R}^3
\end{align}
A linear map from a tangent plane to itself.

I was reading a proof in a book on curves and surfaces and I saw that 
\begin{align*}
W(\sigma_{u}) = -N_{u} \ \text{and} \ W(\sigma_{v}) = - N_{v}
\end{align*}
Where $\sigma_{u}$ is a surface patch differentiated w.r.t. the variable u and $N$ is the standard unit normal.

I have been looking at the above equality, I assume that it is quite obvious, but I don't really get why that is the case?

Comment: What are your definitions? I've seen the Gaussian map **defined** as the unit normal assignment $\nu: M\to S^2$. Then I've seen $W = -d\nu:T_pM\to T_{\nu(p)}S^2 = T_p M$. So $W(\sigma_u)$ is just $-\nu$ differentiated in the direction of $u$, i.e. $W(\sigma_u) = -N_u$ by definition in this formulation.

Comment: For the Gauss map I am using the definition a surface $\mathcal{S'} \subset R^3$ with an orientation $N$(surface normal). Then the map $N: \mathcal{S'} \rightarrow S^2$ takes its values in the unit sphere $S^2$. Then the gauss map is defined as $N: \mathcal{S'} \rightarrow S^{2}$. And the diffrential of the Gauss map is $dN_{p}: T_{p}(S) \rightarrow T_{p}(S) $ where the Weingarten map is defined as $-dN_{p}$

Comment: Yes that's the same definition. Then $df(X)$ is the derivative of f in the direction of the tangent vector X. So $-dN(\partial_u) = -\partial_u N$. Does that make sense?